# how to access an xml with prefix flutter

Tags: xml, flutter, dart

im trying to get a thumbnail image from a link that is in an xml file but im stuck on how to get it,google and previous stackoverlow questions doesnt seem to help
Code:

```
list() {
 return ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _feed.items?.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    final item = _feed.items![index];
    return ListTile(
      title: title(item.title),
      subtitle: subtitle(item.pubDate),

      leading: thumbnail(item.itunes.image),
      trailing: rightIcon(),
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      //onTap: () => openFeed(item.link),
    );
  },
);
```

}
xml :

```
<itunes:image href="link"/>
```

long story short what im trying to do is :

```
thumbnail(get the image link from the <something:another_thing href="link"> href tag),
```

what i dont get is :

1. how to get the itunes:image
2. how to use it to get the contents
   aka link "href='something'"

   **EDIT:**
   solved by simply using :

> **leading: thumbnail(item.itunes!.image!.href)**

Comment: Please update question with what you've tried in Dart so far.

Comment: You can get link like `XmlDocument.parse('<itunes:image href="link"/>').link.nodes.first.attributes.first.value` , here I am using `xml` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
leading: thumbnail(item.itunes!.image!.href)
```